# Quickblox iOS SDK: Using the or custom operator in custom object query

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

The Quickblox docs say you can perform an OR search query using the approach below.

> 1.name[or]=sam,igor
>   2.name[or]=sam&lastname[or]=johnson
>   1.Will return records with name sam or igor
>   2.Will return records with name sam or lastname johnson

Using the code below:

```
NSMutableDictionary *getRequest = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSNumber *userID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:_user.loggedInUser.ID];
[getRequest setObject:userID forKey:@"_user_id[or]"];
[getRequest setObject:userID forKey:@"destination_id[or]"];
[getRequest setObject:@"created_at" forKey:@"sort_desc"];
[QBCustomObjects objectsWithClassName:@"Messages" extendedRequest:getRequest delegate:self context:@"Messages"];
```

The results come back as if I'm performing an AND search on _user_id and destination_id but I need it to perform an OR search on both fields. Can anyone point out how do do this search properly?

Comment: Not sure that you can use _user_id, I think user_id is correct. Read here http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Module_description

Comment: Doing an or search on user_id instead of _user_id works. Though this is confusing because searching on _parent_id works as well as _user_id but when doing an or search you have to use user_id. Seems inconsistent but it does work. Thank you.

Comment: Please use variables format from this guide http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Module_description